# Wordpress acf paragraph doesn't work

Tags: html, css, wordpress, editor, advanced-custom-fields

If I edit the content of my page, the paragraph it doesn't generated:

```
<div class="medium-8 columns">
    <h4>Title</h4>
      HelloWorld
</div>
```

If I justify the content, the paragraph works:

```
    <div class="medium-8 columns">
      <h4>Title</h4>
        <p style="text-align: left;">HelloWorld</p>
    </div>
```

I've searched on Google and I found that it's a problem of Wordpress... It's possible?

PS: If I add `<p></p>` on Text editor, it works, but I want to use the Visual editor

Comment: what do you  mean by generated? not visible or not aligned?

Comment: The text isn't correctly formatted! The paragraph isn't generated

Comment: If you will write this code in visual then it will simply display the code but in text you have to give css as p's css is already defined but you have to define css for div so..